# Logic Error: Inserting Last Node in a Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, logic, singly-linked-list

I am coding a recursive Java method that adds an object node to the end of a linked list. However, instead of executing properly, my current implementation removes all other nodes and just stores the new object value. There are no compilation, runtime exception, or additional logic errors. How can I fix this? (If there is another Stack Overflow that answers this, please post the link.)

Method:

```
public static ListNode insertLast(ListNode head, Object arg) {
      return (head.getNext() != null) ? insertLast(head.getNext(), arg) : new ListNode(arg, null);
}
```

Where head = [computer, science, java, coffee, nonsense, boo, foo, hello], and arg = [p].

Expected (with an object value argument of 'p'): [computer, science, java, coffee, nonsense, boo, foo, hello, p]

Actual (with an object value argument of 'p'): [p]

ListNode Class Implementation (for reference):

```
public class ListNode {
  private Object value;
  private ListNode next;
  public ListNode(Object v, ListNode n) {
    value = v;
    next = n;
  }
  public Object getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  public ListNode getNext() {
    return next;
  }
  public void setValue(Object newv) {
    value = newv;
  }
  public void setNext(ListNode newn) {
    next = newn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your provided implementation, you are creating a new `ListNode` object for the new node to insert, but you are not attaching it to the linked list.

Assuming that you want the `insertLast` method to return the `ListNode` object for the node that was just inserted, you can use the following code:

```java
public static ListNode insertLast(ListNode head, Object arg) {
    if (head.getNext() != null) {
        return insertLast(head.getNext(), arg);
    } else {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(arg, null)
        head.setNext(newNode);
        return newNode;
    }
}
```

The return value of the `insertLast` is the *newly* inserted node, not the head of the linked list. If you want the head of hte linked list, you should use the object that you passed in as the `head` parameter into `insertLast`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code provided, with returning head in the else statement instead of newNode, brought the node before the inserted arg value into the output (hello), but all the nodes before it did not. How can I bring the rest of nodes in head back into the modified linked list?

Comment: How are you outputting the linked list? Can you include the code snippet where you create the linked list, insert the node, and output it?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
      ListNode head = new ListNode("hello", null);
      head = new ListNode("foo", head);
      head = new ListNode("boo", head);
      head = new ListNode("nonsense", head);
      head = new ListNode("coffee", head);
      head = new ListNode("java", head);
      head = new ListNode("science", head);
      head = new ListNode("computer", head);
      print(head);
      head = insertLast(head, "p");
      print(head);
   }

Comment: public static void print(ListNode head) {
      System.out.print("[");
      while (head != null)
      {
         System.out.print(head.getValue());
         head = head.getNext();
         if (head != null) {
            System.out.print(", ");
         }
      }
      System.out.println("]");
   }

Comment: The commenting messed up the format, but the first comment is the main method that creates, modifies, and displays the linked list while the second comment is implementation for printing it.

Comment: When you call `insertLast`, the node that is returned is *not* the head of the list. If you want to print the entire list from the head, you should not re-assign the value of `head`.

`print(head); insertLast(head, "p"); print(head);`

Comment: Well, that fixed it! How could I overlook that? Thank you for the help and have a great day.